# How to hide all the Items created in one particular loop in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsitem, itemgroup

I have been using Qt Creator for almost a month now. I hope this is not a silly question because it bugged me for a long time.

I want to achieve:

- 1. create many different items(let's say 20 per sec) in `QGraphicsScene`.
- 2. use one single class for all these items
- 3. mark all these items, delete or hide them when a signal is triggered.

After trying a lot of methods, the best way I see is to use `QGraphicsItemGroup`. I tried to group all of them into a `QGraphicsItemGroup`. But after adding an item into a group, the item refuses to show on the scene any more, no matter what functions I use from library.

Is there something which I did wrongly in using the `QGraphicsItemGroup`? Or are there any other better apporaches?

Looking forward to anyone's help. Really appreciated.

Followed is a structure of my code:

```
// ......
QGraphicsItemGroup *myItemsGroup = new QGraphicsItemGroup
timer->start(100);
connect(timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(draw_trail()));
// ......
void MyFunction::draw_trail()
{
    Trail_item *new_item = new Trail_item;
    scene->addItem(new_item);
    new_item->setX(COPX-7);    
    new_item->setY(COPY-7);
    new_item->setZValue(5);
    /* 
    then I started trying add to group
    //myItemsGroup->addToGroup(new_item)
    after adding this line, the item vanishes.
    */
}
```

(note: `trail_item` is a item class I created. Since it is a loop, I don't know how to change `*new_item` pointer name, so all items have the same name.)

Comment: Have you added the item group to the scene? The group is visible?

Comment: I will check on that right away. Thanks!

Comment: @Fabio, hi Fabio, sorry for the late reply. I cannot find a function to add a group to scene. I went through the library, I could only found scene->createitemgroup or QGraphicsItemGroup::addToGroup. There are very few functions to use under QGraphicsItemGroup::. However, I know how to set the group visible.

Comment: QGraphicsItemGroup derive from QGraphicsItem, you can add it to the scene as any other item (QGraphicsScene::addItem)

Comment: @Fabio This solved my question! Thanks a lot! This gives me a better understannding of inheritance.

Comment: @Fabio you should create an answer and Sehn Tian should accept it. (based on the comments). This will result in a question that has an answer and the problem is solved.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you have added the `QGraphicsItemGroup` in the scene, and that the `QGraphicsItemGroup` is visible.

You can add the `QGraphicsItemGroup` to the scene as any other `QGraphicsItem`, using the method `QGraphicsScene::addItem(QGraphicsItem*)`